# Why are all my addresses not syncing from iCloud to Mac?

Tags: contacts

I have a laptop running Sierra and a desktop running Sierra. They both sync with the same account on iCloud.

On my desktop, next to the all iCloud link, there is a lightgrey error indicator:

[image].

Also When I click on it I see this odd error message:

[image].

On my laptop, the set of groups displayed is different. in fact there are two groups which appear there, and which also appear in iCloud, which do not appear on my desktop.

I have tried turning off iCloud address book sync on my desktop (all contacts and groups disappear) and turning it back on (all contacts reappear but the groups are wrong.)

I can't explain it. Maybe someone else can? (By the way, this problem occurred before upgrading to Sierra)

Comment: To make sure, this is correct -> occurred before upgrading to Sierra

Comment: @norcaljohnny dont understand your comment.

Comment: You had this problem prior to upgrade?

Comment: Is there anything said in the Console.app? Search for 'Ignored vCard' and see which contact is causing the problem.

Comment: yes I did have this prior to upgrade